# How to paste source code into LaTeX with correct indentation

Tags: listings, sourcecode, python

I am trying to use

```
\begin{lstlisting} 
... 
\end{lstlisting}
```

to include some Python source code in LaTeX.

When I paste the following code block:

```
def plot_c(Yhat, Y, X):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(X, Y)
    plt.plot(X, Yhat)
    ...
```

All the indentations are messed up (or removed in this case) like below:

```
def plot_c(Yhat, Y, X):
plt.figure()
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.plot(X, Yhat)
...
```

Is there any way to past source code directly into LaTeX and keep the original format **without retyping the source code**?

Comment: Use `\lstinputlisting{...}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please note, that this site works best if you (where possible) include a complete compilable minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) which starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`. This way we can help you faster and most likely better!

Comment: Where are you copying the code from? This seems to be specific to the editor that you're using, since a copy-and-paste of the code you provided pastes without problem and even includes the proper indentation (in all basic text editors).

Comment: In general, this is the task of the `verbatim` environment.  Various packages provide added functional or syntax improvements to the basic `verbatim` environment, including `listings`, `minted`, `verbatimbox`, and others.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the [minted package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) to typeset sourcecode.

Please note section 2 *Installation* starting at page 4. You need to have python and pygments installed in order to use minted. (Pygments is the name of the package, pygmentize is the name of the program itself.)

Also, (as explained in 3.1 *Preliminary* on page 6) you must invoke LaTeX with the `-shell-escape` flag if you want to use minted.
For example in TeXstudio open Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Commands and insert `pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` for PdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{python}{%
    % options to customize output of pythoncode
    % see section 5.3 Available options starting at page 16
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pythoncode}
def plot_c(Yhat, Y, X):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(X, Y)
    plt.plot(X, Yhat)
    ...
\end{pythoncode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank  you for your answer. When source code is already written in some other format, Andrew's comment of using  \lstinputlisting{...} did the job without retyping the source code.

Comment: The same can be achieved with `minted` by the `\inputminted` command (cf. p. 8 of the package's manual)

Comment: and there is `\newmintedfile` to create a shortcut for `\inputminted` if you want to include several source code files with the same options (see page 30).

Comment: this is a good package but doesn't answer the question of copying/pasting